# Bring multiple matches with regex in bash, using while

Tags: json, regex, bash, while-loop

So I'm trying to make a bash script which brings the actual weather + some extra info. It should call an API with `curl`, then it gets the info in json, and then parse the information with some regex. The API brings the temp for each hour of the day, which is a lot.

```
#!/bin/bash

text="{                  
    "temp": 286.92,
    "feels_like": 286.05,
    "temp_min": 286.17,
    "temp_max": 286.92,
    "pressure": 1019,
    "sea_level": 1019,
    "grnd_level": 959,
    "humidity": 65,
    "temp_kf": 0.75
    "temp": 263.92,     #<--these 2 "temp" are just examples I put     
    "temp": 277.92,     #in here so I can work better
   },

regex='((temp)...([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+))'

while [[ $text =~ $regex ]]; do
     echo ${BASH_REMATCH}
done
```

I want to get each one of the `"temp":` and print it to the user. It didn't work with an `if` statement because it matches only a single time, so I found that this can be done using a `while` statement. But this one I wrote results in a infinite loop of results!

My desired result is:

```
temp: 286.92
temp: 263.92
temp: 277.92
```

But what I get is an infinite loop of:

```
temp: 286.92
temp: 286.92
temp: 286.92
temp: 286.92
temp: 286.92
temp: 286.92
temp: 286.92
temp: 286.92
temp: 286.92
temp: 286.92
...
```

Comment: what do you get when you `echo ${BASH_REMATCH[@]}`?

Comment: Is it actually in JSON format? 'Cause that wouldn't have more than one "temp" item in a single dictionary.

Comment: Yeah I added these 2 last ones so I could test better using a variable as example, the original output file way bigger

Comment: @RayanAraujo Uning invalid JSON in the example makes it impossible to use proper JSON tools to solve the problem; I'd suggest something like `jq -r '.temp | "temp: " + tostring' <<<"$text"`, but I don't know if that'd work with the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Read each line of the text, and do the pattern matching.

```
   regex='((temp)...([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+))'
   
   IFS=$'\n'; for line in $text; do
   if [[ $line=~ $regex ]]; then
           echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
   fi
done
```

[Live Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/q99d1lARE)

Comment: `for line in $text` does not iterate over lines, it iterates over *words* (and does some other silly things too). See ["Why you don't read lines with `for`"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashFAQ #1: "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 0):

Try learning to use `jq` to deal with JSON in bash. It is powerful and is designed for this.

If your `curl` query returns a single JSON, the command will just do your job:

`curl https://someurl | jq -r '"temp: \(.temp)"'`

If it returns a list of JSON, use the following instead:

`curl https://someurl | jq -r '"temp: \(.[].temp)"'`

Answer (score 0):

Did it.

```
    regex='((temp)...([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+))'

IFS=$'\n ,;'; while read -r line; do
    #echo $line
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo $BASH_REMATCH
    fi
    
done <<< $text
```

Don't even know if `IFS$'\n ,;';` is doing something, but I searched a lot about `for` lops and `while` and it worked, thanks everyone for the help ^^

Comment: Why not use `grep`? Like `grep -oE 'temp...[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+' file`? See the [demo online](https://ideone.com/gDVKgf).